# How to redirect non www to www in rails (using apache + passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I got the below code from earlier threads on SO, I have put this code in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond % ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but after restarting the server, I am not seeing non www redirected to www. What else I need to do ? do I need to edit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default file too ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Taken from [here](http://www.htaccesseditor.com/en.shtml#a_WWW).

Comment: Naah not working it is redirecting to example.com/public url and giving "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Comment: What's `order deny,allow` doing there?

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk - ya, it looks fishy, though I didn't added that anyway

Comment: @iCyborg that rules should work. There is some mistakes but should work. You can safely remove port in rule, it is redundant.